# C #error directive and comments

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Given:

```
#error /*
*/ foo
```

Microsoft C++ outputs an error message of `/*` and GCC outputs `foo`.

Which is correct?

Comment: "Microsoft C++" is a C compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is correct.

Replacement of comments (including line-breaks) happens in translation phase 3, pre-processing in translation phase 4 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999, §5.1.1.2).

Hence, the preprocessing part of the compiler does not "see" the line-breaks anymore.

And, `#error` is defined like this (§6.10.5):

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `# error pp-tokens_opt new-line`
>
> causes the implementation to produce a diagnostic message that includes the specified
>   sequence of preprocessing tokens.

So, the `foo` has to be part of the output.

Answer (score 2):

GCC is correct because it should be replaced by a single space `/ * ... * /` in the standard.